# How to pull form variables from cookies based on drop down selection in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have the following code that when a user selects from a drop down, the `selectedIndex` is used to refer to the corresponding array (`var varNames0, var varNames1`, etc) of form field variables stored in a browser cookie. When the user clicks the edit button, the correct form values should display, along with their values set by the user.

How do I go about pulling the form values correctly, based on the following code. I am almost there, but only seeing the first letter of each array value, and the location in the array is displayed at the bottom of the form that pops up.

```
<a href="#" id="btn_editvars" onclick="showEditVars();">Edit Vars</a>

<select id="product" name="product" >
        <option value="prod1" selected>Prod 1</option>
        <option value="prod2" >Prod 2</option> 
        <option value="prod3" >Prod 3</option>
        <option value="prod4" >Prod 4</option>
</select>

var varNames0 = [
        "property1", 
        "property2",
        "top",
        "property3",
        "property4",
        "closeBtn",
        "loadingText",
        "property5"];

var editableVars = function(){
        var html = "";

        var varNames = "varNames" + document.getElementById("product").selectedIndex;
        for(var i in varNames){
            html += "<p><label for="+varNames[i]+">"+varNames[i]+":</label> <input type=\"text\" id=\""+varNames[i]+"\" placeholder=\"enter "+varNames[i]+"...\" value=\""+socialVars[varNames[i]]+"\" /></p>";

        }
```

Comment: What happens when there is no cookie associated to the dropdown?

Comment: The form will show up with blank fields.

Comment: Currently I am getting the form, but the variables are not showing up correctly, and the fields are showing "undefined".

Answer (score 2):

How about making it a little easier on yourself, if possible, and structuring things like this:

```
var varNames = [
    [
        "property1", 
        "property2",
        "top",
        "property3",
        "property4",
        "closeBtn",
        "loadingText",
        "property5"
    ]
];

var editableVars = function(){
        var html = "";

        var data = varNames[document.getElementById("product").selectedIndex];
        for(var i in data){
            html += "<p><label for="+data[i]+">"+data[i]+":</label> <input type=\"text\" id=\""+data[i]+"\" placeholder=\"enter "+data[i]+"...\" value=\""+socialVars[data[i]]+"\" /></p>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key was to use switch statements:

```
var varNames;
        switch(document.getElementById("product").selectedIndex)
        {
        case 0:
            varNames = varNames0
            break;
        case 1:
            varNames = varNames1
            break;
        case 2:
            varNames = varNames2
            break;
        case 3:
            varNames = varNames3
            break;
        }
```